# devise + OAuth2で画面に『Not found. Authentication passthru.』と表示される

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, devise

エラーの解消方法がわからず、是非皆様のお力を貸して頂けると幸いです。

#### 現状

タイトルの通り、リンクを押下すると画面に『Not found. Authentication passthru.』と表示される
（画面：http://localhost:3000/users/auth/github）

dockerでのエラー内容

```
***-web-1  | Started GET "/users/auth/github" for 172.19.0.1 at 2023-07-13 14:35:23 +0000
***-web-1  | Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#passthru as HTML
***-web-1  |   Rendering text template
***-web-1  |   Rendered text template (Duration: 0.0ms | Allocations: 4)
***-web-1  | Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 278)
```

#### どうしたいか

現状login画面で『GitHubでログイン/登録する』リンクを押下後、githubログインを行いたい

以下を参照して色々試してみたが上手くいかず。
https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview
https://www.takayasugiyama.com/entry/2019/11/09/092017
https://fuga-ch85.hatenablog.com/entry/2021/04/10/075536

#### 補足

GitHub側での`Client ID`, `Client secrets`は設定かつ間違ってないかを確認済み。
以下の設定
Homepage URL : `http://localhost:3000/`
Authorization callback URL : `http://localhost:3000/users/auth/github/callback`

#### 環境

ruby 3.0.2
rails 7.0.4
devise 4.9.2
oauth2 2.0.9
omniauth 2.1.1
omniauth-oauth2 1.8.0
omniauth-github 2.0.1
omniauth-rails_csrf_protection 1.0.1

#### ファイル

users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Users
  class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :github

    def github
      @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

      if @user.present?
        sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
        set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: 'github') if is_navigational_format?
      else
        session["devise.github_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except(:extra)
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
    end

    def failure
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

users/registrations_controller.rb

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Users
  class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    def build_resource(hash = {})
      hash[:uid] = User.create_unique_string
      super
    end

    protected

    def update_resource(resource, params)
      return super if params['password'].present?

      resource.update_without_password(params.except('current_password'))
    end
  end
end
```

models/user.rb

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[github]

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
  validates :phone, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :birthday, presence: true
  validates :uid, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :provider }

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    find_or_create_by(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid) do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end
end
```

views/users/sessions/new.html.erb

```rb
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, html: {'data-turbo' => "false"}, url: session_path(resource_name) ) do |f| %>

  <%= link_to "GitHubでログイン/登録する", user_github_omniauth_authorize_path, method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

config/initializers/devise.rb

```rb
 config.omniauth :github, ENV['CLIENT_ID'], ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'],scope: "user,repo,gist"
```

routes.rb

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount LetterOpenerWeb::Engine, at: '/letter_opener' if Rails.env.development?
  devise_for :users, controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }
  get '/mypage', to: 'mypage#show'
  resources :tasks
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  root 'mypage#show'
end
```

*******_add_omniauth_to_users.rb

```rb
class AddOmniauthToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :provider, :string
    add_column :users, :uid, :string
  end
end
```

Gemfile

```rb
gem 'devise'

gem 'dotenv-rails'

gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-github'
gem "omniauth-rails_csrf_protection"
```

.env

```
CLIENT_ID = '********'
CLIENT_SECRET = '*********'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

下記のサイトを参考にしOmniAuthがPOSTまたはGETメソッドのリクエストを受け入れるように設定をしたら無事に遷移しました。

https://qiita.com/Sugizou0215/items/9fb838793dc8502b97d6